# how to kill Fragment after load it using navigation component

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-components

here's my sample code that i need to kill the fragment after load it in the navHost activity (Main Activity) and i'm using navigation component BTW the Fragment is a **splash screen** Fragment so how to kill it to not shows after loading with back button press.

```
class SplashFragment : Fragment() {

private var _binding: FragmentSplashBinding? = null
private val binding get() = _binding!!

private lateinit var loadingAnim : AnimationDrawable

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    _binding = FragmentSplashBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

    lunchLogoAnimation()
    lunchLoadingAnimation()

    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
        findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_splashFragment_to_homeFragment)

    },6000)


    return binding.root
}

private fun lunchLogoAnimation(){

    val loadAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity,R.anim.splash_screen_logo_translate)
    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
        binding.monkeyLogoSplash.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        binding.monkeyLogoSplash.startAnimation(loadAnimation)
    },500)

}

private fun lunchLoadingAnimation(){

    loadingAnim = binding.loadingDots.drawable as AnimationDrawable

    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
        binding.loadingDots.animate().setDuration(500).alpha(1f).withEndAction {
            loadingAnim.start()
        }
    },1500)

}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    _binding = null
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fragment can be removed easily,

inside the main activity-> kotlin,

```
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(myFragment).commit()
```

or inside the particular fragment,

```
parentFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(this).commit()
```

java

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(myFragment).commit();
```

```
getParentFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(this).commit();
```

Comment: when i put this parentFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(this).commit() inside the handler scope after navigation to homeFragment it's not removed and when i press back button it's load the splash again so what should i do?

Comment: yeah. Oh sorry, my bad. Because you're using navigation components. One solution can be to remove it from the navigation components and start it manually then remove it. I don't really know another solution.

Comment: This is gonna definitely work. Good luck!